# Generate many JPanel in runtime which contain a JList and a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have made an app, that so far places a food order to the system. After placing the order, the order details (Pizzas, drinks etc.) should appear in the chef's screen. This screen will consist of 1 JFrame which contains many JPanels(each of them contains a JList and a JButton). The number of JPanels appearing on the chef's screen has to be equal to the number of orders pending at the moment.

I do not know how to display the order in chef's screen by creating a new Jpanel every time a new order is placed.

Is there any way of doing that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is very possible, the answer will depend on how you want it to look.  You could use a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout` or if you want something more flexible use `MigLayout`

Comment: `This screen will consist of 1 JFrame which contains many JPanels(` Maybe you can use "internal frames'. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of orders at the time is `num`, you can do something like this:

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setBounds(20, 20, 800, 800);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    panels = new JPanel[num];
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        panels[i] = new JPanel();
        panels[i].setLayout(null);
        panels[i].setBackground(Color.cyan);
        panels[i].setBounds(100*i + 10*i, 0, 100, 100); // this is just an example; you can change these numbers
        frame.add(panels[i]);
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

and then add all the add all your order details into a `JTextField` and add the text field to the respective panel. Hope this helps!